# Show that $f(A) = A^2$ is differentiable function mapping $\mathscr{M}_{n\times n}$ to $\mathscr{M}_{n\times n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Show that $f(A) = A^2$ is differentiable function mapping $M_{n\times n}$ to $M_{n\times n}$

In a previous question we showed that for any $A,B \in \mathscr{M}_{n\times n}$ ,
$D_{B}(A) = AB + BA$

to show the proposed map is differentiable we would show

$\lim\limits_{\textbf{h} \to \textbf{0}} \frac{f(a + h) - f(a) - Df(a)h}{\|h\|} = 0$

and in my case specifically:

$\lim\limits_{\textbf{H} \to \textbf{0}} \frac{f(A + H) - f(A) - Df(A)H}{\|H\|} = 0$

Here I'm treating $H$ as the "displacement vector"

To get the total derivative I did the following:

$Df(A) = [AE_1 + E_1A, \dots, AE_{n^2} + E_{n^2}A]$, where the $E_i$ are the standard basis vectors for $M_{n\times n}$ space.

It was suggested to look at these maps through the lense of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Doing that, each component of $Df(A) = [AE_1 + E_1A, \dots, AE_{n^2} + E_{n^2}A]$ will be a vector of length $n^2$ and now doing the correct multiplication against the matrix $H$, adapated into a vector of length $n^2$, I will end up with a vector of length $n^2$. None of this is a problem because putting it together with $f(A + H) - f(A)$, I will get a vector of length $n^2$ coming from
$f(A + H) - f(A) - Df(A)H$.

Doing all this I still don't see any way to get my difference quotient to go to $0$. I played with the individual components of my vectors but that was getting very messy and was not seeing any light at the end of the tunnel. Suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Hopefully this might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4333086/304635

Comment: Yeah I looked at your solution, but I wasn't able to follow the last part of it...

Comment: The point is that you get higher order terms $H^2$ etc, which tend to $0$ when you divide by $\|H\|$

Comment: Oh...I see what you mean, those $H^2$ terms will go to zero faster than our norm and thus will work out for us...In my treatment above I didn't have any squared or higher terms though....

Comment: Well in your case when you expand you should get $f(A+H)=A^2+AH+HA+H^2$. Of course $f(A)=A^2$, the $H^2$ is the higher order term that will tend to $0$ when dividing by $\|H\|$ and that leaves $H\mapsto AH+HA$ as the derivative

Comment: Are you allowed to use any theorems about the form of differentiable functions with values in $\mathbb R^{n^2}$? What I'm particularly thinking about is that a function $F$ with values in $\mathbb R^m$ can be written as a vector of coordinate functions $F = <f_1,...,f_m>$, and there is a very simple theorem saying that $F$ is differentiable if and only if $f_1,...,f_m$ are all differentiable.

Comment: Oh my...when I was looking at my notes I just did I forgot to include the $H^2$ term....

Comment: @jlammy right now I have an expression of the form $\frac{AH + HA + H^2 - [AE_1 + E_1A, \dots, AE_{n^2} + E_{n^2}A]H}{\|H\|}$, so how am I getting the rest to vanish?

Comment: Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a normed algebra. Consider the mapping $f(a)=a^2$ for $a\in \mathcal{B}.$ Let $D_a:\mathcal{B}\to \mathcal{B}$ be defined as $D_a(b)=ab +ba.$ Then $D_a$ is a bounded linear operator on $\mathcal{B}.$ We have $$\|f(a+h)-f(a)-D_a(h)\|=\|h\|^2$$ Hence $$\lim_{\|h\|\to 0}{\|f(a+h)-f(a)-D_a(h)\|\over \|h\|}=0$$ Therefore $(Df)(a)=D_a.$

Comment: So am I treating my "derivative" wrong @RyszardSzwarc ?

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you do not need to use coordinates. Your formula is correct, but it is the same as $B\mapsto AB+BA.$ The latter looks simpler.

Comment: We discussed that answer above @AnneBauval

Comment: Yes, and I think future readers might be more interested by the answers of the duplicate.

Comment: What was the meaning of $D_B(A)$ in the "previous question" where you "showed that [it is] $= AB + BA$"? Some name of map is missing after the $D.$ Wasn't it rather  $DM_B(A)$ or $DM_A(B),$ the differential of $M$ at $A,$ applied to $B,$ where $M$ is the bilinear map $(A,B)\mapsto AB$? (like in the duplicate)